# Google Drive API: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file using API Key

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Drive using the SDK with my app written in VB.Net using API Key and I'm following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#simple

What happens is that when calling the ExecuteAsync method, I receive back an Exception saying that the user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.

Basically, I only have the API key (with restriction to access only Google Drive API) and I don't want to ask the user for permissions, because I'd like to use a specific account (so everyone would be sending files to that account).

I couldn't find a way to "link" this API Key to a specific account also.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue here... What do you mean by this "I don't want to ask the user for permissions, because I'd like to use a specific account"? Moreover, can you share the **full** error message and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ale13 My idea is to have a specific google account and upload files to that account, the user shouldn't select an account like when using Oauth. So every user, when uploading a file, will do for one google account (such as an administrator).

Comment: The authorization still needs to be done in this situation. So I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. Can you share the code as well?

Comment: @ale13 I ended up using a service account. Check my Answer.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) for the Google Drive API.
The idea here was quite simple, where I created this account and downloaded a generated JSON file that is used by the SDK to Authenticate and call the API.

With this service account, I didn't use the API Key and I could leverage [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions)
and set permissions to each user on each created folder.